# Why do I still get a NetworkOnMainThreadException despite using async?

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Here is my program to display results from a web app (data product) I made on an Android device.

```
package studio.nyaa.crimeprediction

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.net.URL
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import com.beust.klaxon.JsonObject
import com.beust.klaxon.Parser
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.async

suspend fun obtainJson():JsonObject {
    val sourceURL = "http://yingzhou474.pythonanywhere.com/api"
    val jsonRes: String = URL(sourceURL).readText()
    val parser: Parser = Parser.default()
    val json = parser.parse(jsonRes) as JsonObject
    Log.d("oj", "oj finished")
    return json
}
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        runBlocking {
            val json = async{obtainJson()}.await()
            Log.d("postcoroutine", json.toString())
            val crime1: Double? = json.obj("data")?.double("AGGRAVATED ASSAULT")
            val crime2: Double? = json.obj("data")?.double("AUTO THEFT")
            val crime3: Double? = json.obj("data")?.double("COMMERCIAL BURGLARY")
            val crime4: Double? = json.obj("data")?.double("HOMICIDE")
            val crime5: Double? = json.obj("data")?.double("LARCENY")
            val crime6: Double? = json.obj("data")?.double("OTHER BURGLARY")
          val crime7: Double? = json.obj("data")?.double("RESIDENTIAL BURGLARY")
          val crime8: Double? = json.obj("data")?.double("ROBBERY")
            val year: Int? = json.int("year")
            val month: Int? = json.int("month")
            val day: Int? = json.int("day")
            val textView1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editText1B)
            textView1.text = crime1?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            val textView2: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editText2B)
            textView2.text = crime2?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            val textView3: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editText3B)
            textView3.text = crime3?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            val textView4: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editText4B)
            textView4.text = crime4?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            val textView5: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editText5B)
            textView5.text = crime5?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            val textView6: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editText6B)
            textView6.text = crime6?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            val textView7: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editText7B)
            textView7.text = crime7?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            val textView8: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editText8B)
            textView8.text = crime8?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            val textViewDate: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editTextDate)
            textViewDate.text = "Date: $month/$day/$year"
        }
    }
}
```

Here the data source is [this site](http://yingzhou474.pythonanywhere.com/api) which returns a JsonObject of this kind:

```
{"data": {"AGGRAVATED ASSAULT": 6.87, "AUTO THEFT": 4.4, "COMMERCIAL BURGLARY": 1.3, "HOMICIDE": 0.62, "LARCENY": 30.72, "OTHER BURGLARY": 0.59, "RESIDENTIAL BURGLARY": 4.21, "ROBBERY": 3.16}, "year": 2019, "month": 8, "day": 20}
```

Edited2: I fixed the Klaxon error on my own.

Edited: After fixing this now I'm getting something else:

```
08-19 23:13:32.385 2175-2175/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: studio.nyaa.crimeprediction, PID: 2175
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{studio.nyaa.crimeprediction/studio.nyaa.crimeprediction.MainActivity}: java.io.FileNotFoundException: {"data": {"AGGRAVATED ASSAULT": 6.87, "AUTO THEFT": 4.4, "COMMERCIAL BURGLARY": 1.3, "HOMICIDE": 0.62, "LARCENY": 30.72, "OTHER BURGLARY": 0.59, "RESIDENTIAL BURGLARY": 4.21, "ROBBERY": 3.16}, "year": 2019, "month": 8, "day": 20}: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5418)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: {"data": {"AGGRAVATED ASSAULT": 6.87, "AUTO THEFT": 4.4, "COMMERCIAL BURGLARY": 1.3, "HOMICIDE": 0.62, "LARCENY": 30.72, "OTHER BURGLARY": 0.59, "RESIDENTIAL BURGLARY": 4.21, "ROBBERY": 3.16}, "year": 2019, "month": 8, "day": 20}: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
    at com.beust.klaxon.Parser$DefaultImpls.parse(Parser.kt:21)
    at com.beust.klaxon.KlaxonParser.parse(KlaxonParser.kt:9)
    at studio.nyaa.crimeprediction.MainActivityKt.obtainJson(MainActivity.kt:16)
    at studio.nyaa.crimeprediction.MainActivity$onCreate$1$json$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:25)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
    at com.beust.klaxon.Parser$DefaultImpls.parse(Parser.kt:21) 
    at com.beust.klaxon.KlaxonParser.parse(KlaxonParser.kt:9) 
    at studio.nyaa.crimeprediction.MainActivityKt.obtainJson(MainActivity.kt:16) 
    at studio.nyaa.crimeprediction.MainActivity$onCreate$1$json$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:25) 
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241) 
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594) 
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60) 
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740) 
08-19 23:13:32.555 2175-2175/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2175 SIG: 9
```

**Old stuff:**

Despite using `async` and `await` I still got the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Here is my stack trace:

```
08-19 22:28:06.675 28015-28015/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: studio.nyaa.crimeprediction, PID: 28015
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{studio.nyaa.crimeprediction/studio.nyaa.crimeprediction.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5418)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
    at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
    at kotlin.io.TextStreamsKt.readBytes(ReadWrite.kt:150)
    at studio.nyaa.crimeprediction.MainActivityKt.obtainJson(MainActivity.kt:17)
    at studio.nyaa.crimeprediction.MainActivity$onCreate$1$json$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:28)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:270)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:79)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:54)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:36)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at studio.nyaa.crimeprediction.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6083)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5418) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1037) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

This question is a variant of [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565463/why-doesnt-my-kotlin-coroutine-run-at-all?noredirect=1#comment101595281_57565463).

Comment: I think it is because runBlocking runs on main thread and async doesn't change the current thread it is on. How about switch to default dispatcher to run on different thread for async task?

Comment: @PoePoe Thanks! You guys are all correct! However now this problem of `FileNotFoundException` returned. Is there anything I'm missing with respect to `Klaxon`?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

As you can only mark one answer as correct solution, I'd suggest asking in a new question.

Comment: @isaaaaame Yep. I have done that. I solved the Klaxon problem on my own.

Comment: `{"data": {"AGGRAVATED ASSAULT": 6.87, "AUTO THEFT": 4.4, "COMMERCIAL BURGLARY": 1.3, "HOMICIDE": 0.62, "LARCENY": 30.72, "OTHER BURGLARY": 0.59, "RESIDENTIAL BURGLARY": 4.21, "ROBBERY": 3.16}, "year": 2019, "month": 8, "day": 20}` isn't a filename.

Comment: Please don't use `runBlocking`!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because **async** block is running with **Dispatchers.Main** try using it with **Dispatchers.IO**

```
val json = async(Dispatchers.IO){obtainJson()}.await()
```

Also a better syntax would be to use withContext

```
val json = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){obtainJson()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call network in the main thread. You can fix it by using `IO` dispatcher:

```
async(Dispatchers.IO){ obtainJson() }.await()
```

Answer (score 1):

You **should not** use `runBlocking {}` in production code! It'll block your main thread.

Since you're calling this within the main thread, every following call to `async` or `launch` will be run in the same scope and thus on the main thread.

Instead you should launch a coroutine preferable with a `viewModelScope` (`GlobalScope` would be an acceptable start as well) and run the view updates on the main thread:

```
GlobalScope.launch(IO) {
    val json = obtainJson()
    Log.d("postcoroutine", json.toString())
    val crime1: Double? = json.obj("data")?.double("AGGRAVATED ASSAULT")
    ...
    val year: Int? = json.int("year")
    val month: Int? = json.int("month")
    val day: Int? = json.int("day")
    launch(Main) {
        val textView1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editText1B)
        textView1.text = crime1?.toString() ?: "N/A"
        ...
        val textViewDate: TextView = findViewById(R.id.editTextDate)
        textViewDate.text = "Date: $month/$day/$year"
    }
}
```

Using `async` is not necessary here. Instead of `launch(Main)` you could use `withContext(Main)` though.